# Break from an if statement into the else section

Tags: objective-c, c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have an if/else statement.

```
if (something) {
    //run if logic
} else {
    //run else logic
}
```

During my `if logic phase`, I may find something that makes me want to run the else portion of my if/else statement instead. The logic phase is too complex to just fit in the initial conditional, `something`.

Is there anything like `break;` that can be used to jump to the `else` portion of an if/else statement.

I'm currently doing this, but my team dislikes using goto

```
if (something) {
    //run if logic
    if (somethingComplex) {
        goto elseSomething;
    }
} else {
    elseSomething:
    //run else logic
}
```

*Note again that `somethingElseComplex` is a boolean state achieved by running some complex code too big/multi-lined to fit in my initial if conditional, otherwise I would have just done: `if (something && somethingComplex)`, and if I calculate somethingComplex before the first conditional is called I can get false-positive results. on `!something` values*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C, I'd use a boolean flag set beforehand, and not use `if/else` but rather two separate `if` statements, like this (this is Swift code, but it's the same structure):

```
var needToDoSomethingElseComplex = false
if something {
    // do stuff
    if somethingComplex {
        needToDoSomethingElseComplex = true
    }
}
if !something || needToDoSomethingElseComplex {
    // do something else complex
}
```

But *real* Swift would give you an elegant way to do exactly what you're looking for — a `switch` with a `fallthrough`:

```
switch something {
case true:
    print("hey")
    if somethingComplex {
        fallthrough
    }
    print("ho")
case false:
    print("ha")
}
```

In the above, if `something` is true, and if `somethingComplex` turns out to be true, we print "hey" then "ha", which is precisely the flow you are looking for.

Comment: This isn't an exact answer to what I'm asking—however, I think what I'm asking has no answer. That said, this is the next simplest way imo; thank-you!

Comment: Real Swift would give you an actual way to do what you want (a `switch` with a `fallthrough`), but Objective-C does not. Another reason to switch (no pun intended) to Swift! I'll add that point to my answer.

Comment: wow! Fallthrough is neat! I'm very tempted to `switch` to swift.

Comment: Allows for a creative solution to FizzBuzz too haha

Answer (score 2):

There's no language feature apart from `goto` that allows you to transfer control arbitrarily like this.

The other, better way to move from two places in code to one other place is using a procedure: a method or function. I think factoring out the contents of the `else` branch is in order here. Then call the new procedure from the inner `if` and the `else` branch.

You might also consider refactoring the initial condition. There ought to be some way that you can combine those two checks without having to smash them into the parentheses of an `if()`'s header.

Answer (score 1):

What about...

```
BOOL shouldGoToB = false;
if (a) {
    //run if logic
    if (somethingComplex) {
        shouldGoToB = YES;
    }
}

if (!a || shouldGoToB) {
}
```